# return value problem when calculating a polynomial function

Tags: c, pointers, return

I am trying to get the value of a polynomial function with a return value but it seems that something is going wrong with the variables.

Maybe I made a mistake writing the series equation inside the function. But I couldn't debug the code either since it crashes unexpectedly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

double PolinomHesapla(double *p, int N, double x)
{

double total = 0;


int j;

for (j=0; j < N; j++)
{

total += p[j] * pow(x,N);  

}



return total;


}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

double x_point;
int n;
int i;     // iteration variable
double a[n];     // we put the coefficients inside a[n] array

printf("Enter the order of the polynomial function: "); 

scanf("%d", &n);

printf("Enter the coefficients of the function:  "); 

for(i=0; i < n ; i++)
{
    scanf("%f",&a[i]); 

}

printf("Enter the point of x in the function\t:");

scanf("%f",&x_point); 


printf("The value of the function at that point is\t %f",PolinomHesapla(a,n,x_point));  // we send the values 
                                                                                    // into PolinomHesapla function


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are declaring your variable-length array `a` to have length `n` before assigning any value to `n`.  The resulting behavior is undefined.  If you must use a VLA, then read (and validate) the wanted value of `n` before declaring the array.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed!!!